# Creating a Java Desktop UI which can be understood by Eclipse and Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jsr296

**Netbeans** recently [dropped support](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic43775.html) for Swing based Java Desktop Applications from version 7.1 onwards. Till that point I had always imagined that creation of Java Application User Interfaces would be cross platform. I thought that a Swing UI created in Netbeans designer could be easily understood and edited in **Eclipse** but apparently now I realize that it is not the case.

Is there a way to make the Java Application User Interface by not depending on IDE-specific Java UI designers? That is a form of UI description, can be XML or something that can be edited on the different IDEs that people would like to use.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11096999/230513).

Answer (score 4):

That post starts..

> I just installed NB 7.1 Beta, and tried to open one of our many Swing Application **Framework**-based applications, ..

OK.  You can stop reading there, sounds like [JSR 296](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/) which has been dying for years.  Pure Swing apps. should be fine.